# why the img on the two sites are different

Tags: html, css

Site 1: http://www.velop.org/, and site 2: http://sandbox.velop.org/, the velop logo on the site 2 seems bigger than the one on http://www.velop.org/, i checked the source code with firebug, the image is the same size 240px*62px, but why they look different?

Comment: font weight is different . ( hey, this is not programming question , but why am I answering this ? = = )

Comment: Why are the images different? Because they are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just different images.

http://www.needsmet.org/graphics/velop.jpg

http://sandbox.velop.org/styles/default/velop/images/logo-large.png

Comment: with different sizes too, in the page

Answer (score 0):

Two images are REALLY different:

[image: In Sandbox]

[image: In WWW]